Асинхронность при рисовании в windowsForms
Мне нужно отрисовать линейный список по этапам, параллельно выводя сопровождающий текст на каждом этапе, для этого я попытался добавить либо ожидание с помощью
await Task.Delay(2000);
Либо
Thread.Sleep(2000);
Оно происходит в непонятном порядке.
Пробовал я через ожидание нажатия кнопки, в таком случае программа крашится после первого же ожидания при первом вызове отрисовки. В интернетах я увидел, что асинхронность в отрисовке невозможна, но неужто нет никакого выхода?
Код правок:
namespace DataStucturesVisualizer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private LinkedList<int> linkedList = new LinkedList<int>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listPanel.Paint += (s, e) => DrawLinkedListAsync(e.Graphics);
        }

        private async Task DrawNodeAsync(Graphics g, int x, int y, string value, bool isLastNode)
        {
            int width = 80;
            int height = 50;
            int splitHeight = height / 2;


            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, x, y, width, height);
            AddCommandToFlowLayoutPanel("new(p)");
            await Task.Delay(1000);

            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x, y + splitHeight, x + width, y + splitHeight);
            AddCommandToFlowLayoutPanel("read(f, p^.inf)");
            await Task.Delay(1000);

            g.DrawString(value, new Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Black, x + 5, y + 5);
            AddCommandToFlowLayoutPanel("read(f, p^.inf)");
            await Task.Delay(1000);

            if (isLastNode)
            {
                g.DrawString("nil", new Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Black, x + 5, y + splitHeight + 5);
                AddCommandToFlowLayoutPanel("p^.next := nil");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }
        private void AddCommandToFlowLayoutPanel(string command)
        {

            Label commandLabel = new Label
            {
                Text = command,
                AutoSize = true,
                Font = new Font("Arial", 12),
                ForeColor = Color.Black,
                Padding = new Padding(5)
            };


            commandFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(commandLabel);
        }
        private async Task DrawArrowAsync(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
        {

            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x1, y1, x2, y2);
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x2, y2, x2 - 5, y2 - 5);
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x2, y2, x2 - 5, y2 + 5);


            AddCommandToFlowLayoutPanel("p^.next := nil");
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }

        private async Task DrawLinkedListAsync(Graphics g)
        {
            int x = 10, y = 10;
            const int nodeSpacing = 100;

            int visibleXStart = -listPanel.AutoScrollPosition.X;
            int visibleXEnd = visibleXStart + listPanel.Width;

            var current = linkedList.First;
            while (current != null)
            {
                string value = current.Value.ToString();
                bool isLastNode = current.Next == null;


                if (x + 80 >= visibleXStart && x <= visibleXEnd)
                {

                    await DrawNodeAsync(g, x, y, value, isLastNode);

                    if (!isLastNode)
                    {
                        int arrowX1 = x + 40;
                        int arrowY1 = y + 50;
                        int arrowX2 = x + nodeSpacing;
                        int arrowY2 = y + 50;

                        await DrawArrowAsync(g, arrowX1, arrowY1, arrowX2, arrowY2);
                    }
                }
                x += nodeSpacing;
                current = current.Next;
            }
        }


        private static async Task WaitForButtonClick(Button button)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            EventHandler handler = null;
            handler = (s, e) =>
            {
                tcs.SetResult(true);
                button.Click -= handler;
            };

            button.Click += handler;

            await tcs.Task;
        }

        private void UpdateVisualization()
        {
   
            int totalWidth = linkedList.Count * 100;
            listPanel.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(totalWidth, listPanel.Height);


            listPanel.Refresh();
        }


        private async void listPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;


            g.TranslateTransform(listPanel.AutoScrollPosition.X, listPanel.AutoScrollPosition.Y);


            await DrawLinkedListAsync(g);
        }



        private void addNode(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(inputTextBox.Text, out int value))
            {
                linkedList.AddFirst(value);

                UpdateVisualization();
            }
        }

        private void removeNode(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (linkedList.Count > 0)
            {
                linkedList.RemoveFirst();
                UpdateVisualization();
            }
        }
    }

}


Вы обсуждаете код, который не показыаете, а это смысла не имеет. Но в теории, когда вы используете Thread.Sleep вы фризите поток, если это делать в UI потоке, то программа как будто подвисает и в этом случае не сможет отрисовать себя. То есть с использованием Thread.Sleep, если вы что то рисуете и для пауз используете Thread.Sleep, то у вас сначала всё подвиснет и потом разом всё отрисует. При использовании асинхронности, у вас между вызовами Task.Delay будет перерисовываться окно, но await Task.Delay(1000) может занять больше секунды, оно не точное.

по итогу, если у вас есть данные, которые вам надо отрисовать просто шаг за шагом, то я бы советовал await Task.Delay() использовать или таймеры, но не Thread.Sleep

await Task.Delay(1000); // Ожидаем нажатия кнопки - этот код не ожидает никакой кнопки, если вам надо ждать нажатия кнопки, то пользуйтесь паттерном "Машина состояний", тогда и ждать не придется ничего, код будет просто реагировать на события от UI и менять на нужное состояние.

@tym32167 комментарий остался от прошлой версии кода

В принципе, у вас вполне рабочий код. Вопрос лишь в том, что происходит при нажатии какой-то неведомой кнопки. А также какой именно графикс используется.
